# Find selected text start and end index with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ios, xhtml, dom-events

I have one ePub Book XHTML page with many p(paragraph) tags in it.

Now I am getting selected text index with respect of body tag by below function in JS:

```
var fullString = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].textContent;
if (window.getSelection) 
{               
    var range = window.getSelection ();                     
    var startPosition = fullString.search(range);
    var getPosition = range.toString();
    var endPosition = parseInt(getPosition.length) + parseInt(startPosition);
    alert("Start position if : " + startPosition + " and End position : " + endPosition);
    start_position = startPosition;
    end_position = endPosition;                               
}
```

It is returning me correct index while selection is in only one P tag.

But as selection covers more than one p tag I am getting start position as "-1".

Can you please help me to get out from this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the line below you will get it working.

var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: AmGates, I have used this before I have implement above code..the problem is with your suggestion is it will give me range according to Paragraph tag not according to all the text in my body tag.

Comment: Hey I have tried this code suggested. I didn't understand what you are trying to say.